# Make WPF control over the web browser

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I have a WPF application in which I have an embedded web browser control. I want to show an animation over the web browser at a certain time, but the problem is that the WPF controls, when kept over the web browser are not visible.

Is there any way to show my user control over the web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please answer me this first,

Is this Web Browser control the `WPF Web Browser` Control or `Winform` webbrowser control hosted in `WinFormHost`?

For any WPF control to show animation over it, did you explore ...

1. Placing your control in `Grid` or `Canvas` and then placing an stretched `Border` (which has running animation in it) as the last child of the grid/canvas?
2. `Adorner` with constantly changing drawing context to simulate animations?
3. Transparent `Popup` with animation, whose static placement is done (bound to control's absolute left, top positions and actual height & width properties) over the control?

Try the transparent popup approach for web browser control ...

```
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser1"/> 
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding StartAninmation}"
              AllowsTransparency="True"
              Grid.RowSpan="99"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="99"
              Placement="Center"
              Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                              ElementName=WebBrowser1,
                              Mode=OneWay}"
              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, 
                               ElementName=WebBrowser1,
                               Mode=OneWay}"
              PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=WebBrowser1}"
              Opacity="0.5"
              Margin="3">
           <TextBlock Text="Loading ..."/>
       </Popup>
 </Grid>
```

One of these will surely work in your case.

Comment: The WPF Web Browser control is technically a wrapped WinForms WebBrowser Control, so it is rendered in the WinForms layer, which is always above the WPF layer. 
Adorners and Popups will therefore not work :(

Comment: I have used Transparent `Popup` successfully as far as I remember.

Comment: +1, Even I have used transparent popups for this exact requirement.

Comment: Okay guys my mistake, Popup renders another Window so it works, Adorner renders in the visual tree and will not work, just tested it out, thanks for the correction on this ! ...

Comment: What if the over control is outside of the   <Grid> where WebBrowser is. Will it work? Let's Say we have Canvas and 2 usercontrols one of them has webbriowser. And I want to put over of it. Will covering control be over of the WebBrowser?

Comment: yes why not. Only thing is popup has to be **hosted somewhere** in the visual tree.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately thats not possible with the WPF Webbrowser Control (which is basically a wrapped WinForms WebBrowser control), due to the order the OS renders WinForms and WPF content.

See also:
[Is there a way to render WPF controls on top of the wpf WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926617/is-there-a-way-to-render-wpf-controls-on-top-of-the-wpf-webbrowser-control)

There's a third party app [Awsomium](http://awesomium.com/) that should make it possible.

*Edit:* Another possibility would be to render a frameless window above the WebBrowser Control. But it's a bit tricky to keep it in the correct position/z-order.

Answer (score 1):

[CefSharp](https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp) provides a pure WPF browser contorl based on Chromium/V8 that isn't subject to the airspace issues of the Microsoft WebBrowser control (disclaimer: I am the maintainer of CefSharp).

Comment: no need to build, you can use a binary release: https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp/downloads

Comment: Anthony, how come it is impossible to build btw? :) I just tried with my VS2012 and failed. I tried with both chillitom's branch and yours. Complains about a load of external references.