# Place control on top of Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView

Tags: wpf, webview, windows-community-toolkit

```
<Grid>
    <!-- xmlns:webview="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView" -->
    <webview:WebView ... /> 

    <Grid x:Name="Overlay"
          Panel.ZIndex="1000"
          Background="Red"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

I am trying to overlay a `WebView` with another control (`Overlay`). But it seems that the `WebView` is always on top of other controls.

Is there a way to place controls on top of a `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView`?

Comment: Wrap the WPF content in a popup, as shown in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073583/2363460

Answer (score 2):

The Webview control is a  [wrapped UWP control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) which in turn wraps a win32 component I believe.

Due to airspace problems this control will not support transparency and will always be rendered on top. See here for a better description:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/technology-regions-overview

Although it is possible to [run it in a popup as a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206967/make-wpf-control-over-the-web-browser), it might not be very futureproof: 
*"WebView controls can be hosted in a popup window. We recommend that you do not do this because support for that scenario will soon be disabled for security reasons."*
[See here for more](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/3.0.0-preview/docs/controls/WebView-known-issues.md)

[CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) might be a better solution. It it based on Chromium and there is a Nuget package available. In the example below a red grid is rendered over the browser:

```
<Grid>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions" />
    <Grid x:Name="Overlay"
    Height="100"
    Background="Red"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>   
</Grid>
```

Output:

[image: Cefsharp]