# How to open User control as Popup on top of webbrowser WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, webbrowser-control

The hierarchy is as follows

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser ></WebBrowser>
</Grid>
```

Now I want to add another child to the *Grid* which will be shown as a PopUp. This works everywhere but when we have a *WebBrowser* as a child in the Grid it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, its not possible with Webbrowser Control in WPF.

`WebBrowser` control what you are using is not an actual WPF control.  Its just a wrapped winforms webcontrol .  Its impossible to show the WPF content on top of it.

**Similar questions in SO where you can see for workaround:**

- [Is there a way to render WPF controls on top of the wpf WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926617/is-there-a-way-to-render-wpf-controls-on-top-of-the-wpf-webbrowser-control)
- [Make WPF control over the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206967/make-wpf-control-over-the-web-browser)