# change scrollbar inside scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar, scrollviewer

there is a grid inside scrollviewer which is having a vertical scrollbar. But that scroll bar is not clear, there are 2 small horizontal lines at the bottom of scrollbar.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="DetailsBackButton" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Click="AttachementDetailsBackButton_Click" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListBox x:Name="DetailsListbox" BorderBrush="#d2d4d5" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12px" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ActualHeight}" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxDefaultStyle}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0"  Style="{DynamicResource AttachmentTitleText}" MouseLeftButtonDown="AttachmentTitle_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Border Style="{DynamicResource AreaButtonBorder}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" Style="{DynamicResource WebBrowserStyle}" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Navigating="FullTextWebBrowser_Navigating" LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_LoadCompleted"  />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And further, if I am scrolling it a bit, these 2 horizontal lines will go off.  how this can be solved? or Is there any way to move the scroll bar little down by default inside scrollviewer? 
Thanks.[image]

Comment: I suspect your `WebBrowser` control for this. Normally all other items should be inside the `ScrollViewer` and not on top of it. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926617/is-there-a-way-to-render-wpf-controls-on-top-of-the-wpf-webbrowser-control

Comment: if we minimize the word, there are 2 scrollbars visible. It seems that 2 horizontal lines are because of merging of these 2 scroll bars. But even after disabling the outer scroll bar, I was able to see the horizontal lines on single scroll bar. Now, I need to recognize that this scroll bar is exactly related to which control. I had already given the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" for the 2 grids inside scrollviewer and for the web browser control also, but the scroll bar is not related to them.

Comment: To be able to give you an answer you have to make a [MCVE question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the example above there is no chance we can provide you a usable answer, only guesses

Comment: is there any way to make web browser scroll bar as hidden but still the web browser content should be scrollable by using scroll bar of any other control in the above code. because the issue is with scroll bar of web browser.