# How to display progress bar on top of the web browser in a popup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, z-index

I have a web browser and progress bar in a parent popup control. When the application is not running, in the design view the progress bar is being shown on top of the web browser, but as soon as the application runs the progress bar goes behind web browser. I have tried using the ZIndex also, but in vain.

Please help me with this because I have this requirement that when the content is being loaded in web browser, the progress bar should be shown at the top of blank web browser.

Code is something of this sort:

```
<Grid>
    <Popup
        IsOpen="True"
        StaysOpen="True"
        Placement="Center"
        Height="100"
        Width="200">
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <WebBrowser
                    Grid.ZIndex="1"
                    Visibility="Visible"
                    Margin="10"
                    Source="D:\Temp\gui1_Help.html">
                </WebBrowser>
                
                <ProgressBar 
                    Grid.ZIndex="2"
                    Height="50"
                    Visibility="Visible"
                    IsIndeterminate="True"
                    >

                </ProgressBar>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>

</Grid>
```

This image shows progress bar on top of web browser (When the application is not running):

[image: This image shows progress bar on top of web browser (When the application is not running).]

This image shows progress bar goes behind web browser (When the application is running):
[image: This image shows progress bar on top of web browser (When the application is not running).]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the WPF WebBrowser control is actually just a wrapped version of the WinForms control.

See: [Make WPF control over the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206967/make-wpf-control-over-the-web-browser)

See: [Is there a way to render WPF controls on top of the wpf WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926617/is-there-a-way-to-render-wpf-controls-on-top-of-the-wpf-webbrowser-control)

And due to the rendering order of WPF, WinForms will always be rendered on top of WPF controls.

You have two options:

1. Go with a 3rd party WPF control (to avoid WinForms altogether), such as [CESSharp](https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp).
2. Place your progress bar inside of a new Window that has WindowStyle=None and sized to just the progress bar, and place it on top of your browser.  The huge downside to this is maintaining the window position if your browser or main window is resized.